# Error in sql query with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

and here is my code

```
<?php 
$titulo = "Baja de usuario";
require "conexion.php";
$usu_nombre = $_POST["usu_nombre"];
$usu_id = $_POST["usu_id"];
$sql = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE usu_id = ".$usu_id;

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$chequeo = mysqli_affected_rows($link);

include "encabezado.php"; 
?>
```

Can't really find the syntax error there, any idea?

the $_POST["usu_id"] comes from here:

```
$titulo = "Formulario de baja- Usuarios - Proyecto integrador";
    require "conexion.php";
    $usu_id = $_GET["usu_id"];
    $sql = "SELECT usu_id, usu_login ,usu_clave, usu_nombre, usu_email FROM usuarios WHERE usu_id = ".$usu_id;
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
<?php include "encabezado.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top"><img src="imagenes/top.png" alt="encabezado" width="980" height="80"></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <?php  include "menu.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <h1><?php echo $titulo ; ?></h1>
        <!-- inicio del desarrollo -->
    <form action = "baja-usuario.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return confirmarBaja()">
        <table id="paneles">
            <tr>
                <th colspan ="5">Se eliminara el siguiente usuario</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Login</th>
                <th>Clave</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_id"] ;?></td>
                <td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_login"]; ?></td>  
                <td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_clave"] ;?></td>
                <td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_nombre"] ;?></td>
                <td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_email"] ;?></td>                                          
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type= "hidden" name = "usu_id" value = "<?php echo $fila["usu_id"]; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type= "hidden" name = "usu_nombre" value = "<?php echo $fila["usu_nombre"]; ?>"></td> <!-- el input type hidden no renderiza el valor pero si sirve para pasarlo como parametro en el FROM -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2" class ="centrar"><input type = "submit" value = "Eliminar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and the usu_id from the : `<td class = "lista"><?php echo $fila["usu_id"] ;?></td>` displays correctly, showing the ID

Comment: make sure that POST array isn't empty and isn't a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - if it's a string `WHERE usu_id = '$usu_id'";` - Form method must be POST and that the element does contain the correct name attribute.

Comment: its and id that comes from a form. : '<td><input type= "hidden" name = "usu_id" value = "<?php echo $fila["usu_id"] ?>"></td>'

Comment: then your initial query for it failed and isn't being populated correctly or not at all. Not enough code in your question. view html source for it and see what it shows you. and post the full code for this. blind guess: should be a GET for the id.

Comment: echo out $usu_id under the line  $usu_id = $_POST["usu_id"]; to check to see if data is being passed

Comment: `$usu_id = $_POST["usu_id"];` => `$usu_id = $_GET["usu_id"];` and use a conditional `if(!empty())` for it.

Comment: get? but it comes from a <form>

Comment: it's coming from a pre-fetched from db, *n'est-ce pas?* ;-) just try it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: usu_id in C:\xamppReal\htdocs\fela\sistema\baja-usuario.php on line 5

Comment: line 5 being the one i changed to _GET

Answer (score 0):

The error was that i was using `<?php while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ ?>` and so the usu_id the form send to the POST, was empty beacuse of the msqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: For future reference, you can get much more comprehensive error information by adding the following to the top of your PHP code: `ini_set("display_errors", "1"); ini_set("html_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);` You can also set these values in your `php.ini` file if you have access to it, and always look in your server's `error.log` file for the error messages.